# Visual C# 2010 - Comma separate contents of Text Box

Tags: c#, regex, text, split, textbox

I'm trying to create an application where the end user can copy and paste a number of email addresses into a text box, these email addresses will then all be moved onto one line and separated with a comma and a space, apart from the last one, the resulting value will then be assigned to a variable.

How can I split up and comma separate the text value of the textbox as required?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, when you say you want the email addresses moved onto one line, is this in some kind of display field or into another text box or something?

Comment: Some further details would be nice. What should the user be able to copy into the textbox? Only emails separated with whitespace etc.? What kind of textbox do you mean? WPF, WinForms, ASP, other?

Comment: I think he wants to validate "foo@bar.com, foo@bar.com, foo@bar.com" as correct and "foo@bar.com, foo@bar.com, foo@bar.com, " as incorrect. And when save strip out any new lines. I suspect regex will solve it

Comment: -1: Sorry, but there isn't enough information in this question for us to be able to provide help. Can you 1) Please clarify what you're trying to do, and 2) Show us/tell us what you've already tried and why it isn't working for you. If you edit your question and add more detail I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll need to assume that these email addresses will be like:

"email1; email2; email3; emailN"

You can use String.Split method:

```
string[] emailAddresses = txtBox.Text.Split(";");
```

Is this what you're looking for?